# How to find the program that is running a python file

Tags: python-3.x

How do you find the file that is running or debugging a python file (*i.e* if you run your python file in Visual studio code, it will output "Code.exe", which is the name of the exe file that VS code runs on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is a mix of python `os.getppid()` to get the parent id, and [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to get the executable name

```py
import os
import psutil

parent_id = os.getppid()

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.pid == parent_id:
        print(proc)
        print(proc.name())
        break
```

```
psutil.Process(pid=11172, name='pycharm64.exe', status='running', started='21:30:50')
pycharm64.exe
```

and yes that code ran in pycharm.

**Edit:** in Vscode, because Vscode runs powershell as a child then runs python from it, it gets more involved, and you have to climb to the last grandparent, but using the solution from [this psutil gist](https://gist.github.com/danbradham/2b00d7523740dceabf376c3ded30345c) with some modifications.

```py
import os
import psutil

def get_parent_process(limit=10):
    depth = 0
    this_proc = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    next_proc = psutil.Process(this_proc.ppid())
    while depth < limit:

        try:
            next_proc = psutil.Process(next_proc.ppid())
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess as e:
            return next_proc.name()
        depth += 1

    return next_proc.name()
    
print(get_parent_process())
```

```
Code.exe
```

Comment: This works great, but is there any way to make some code that outputs code.exe if run in vscode and also outputs pycharm.exe when run in pycharm?

Comment: @TullyYT The second code will work on both cases, as long as both have no parent, ie: both were launched by double clicking their exe, an alternative is to do `if next_proc.name() in ["Code.exe","pycharm64.exe"]: break`